# Flexbox item height when containing input tags in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/28vyvocm/2/ I have a flexbox with two items in it. The second is stretching from the bottom of the first to the bottom of the screen. What I noticed in IE 11 is that when the first item contains input tags, IE adds a padding or margin to the bottom of the item. The more input tags you have, the larger the margin. This does not occur in Chrome or Firefox.
Am I missing something or is this a known issue with IE?

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.nonflexitem {
  background-color: orange;
}
.flexitem {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nonflexitem">
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
      <input type="text">
      <BR />
    </div>
    <div class="flexitem">
      Flex item
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: IE11 is known for having many [***flexbugs***](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs). In this case, however, why all the `<br>` tags? Just make your `.nonflexitem` flex item a nested flex container in column-direction (like the parent), remove all the breaks, and it works cross-browser: https://jsfiddle.net/28vyvocm/3/

Comment: This is just an example.In reality the input tags are inside a table.